# Find limit of $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^{200}(x)}{x^{199}\sin(4x)}$, if it exists

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, trigonometry, derivatives

I'm practising solving limits and the one I'm currently struggling with is the following: $$\ell =\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^{200}(x)}{x^{199}\sin(4x)}$$

**What I've done:**

- Since this is an obvious $0/0$ , I tried using de L'Hospital's Rule consecutively only to see both the numerator and the denominator grow so much in size that each couldn't fit in one row.
  $$
  \begin{align}
  l
  & =\lim_{x→0}{{\sin^{200}(x)}\over{x^{199}\sin(4x)}}\\
  & = \lim_{x→0}{{200\sin^{199}(x)\cos(x)}\over{x^{198}\left(199\sin\left(4x\right)+4x\cos\left(4x\right)\right)}}\\
  & = \lim_{x→0}{{39800\cos^2\left(x\right)\sin^{198}\left(x\right)-200\sin^{200}\left(x\right)}\over{x^{198}\left(800\cos\left(4x\right)-16x\sin\left(4x\right)\right)+198x^{197}\left(199\sin\left(4x\right)+4x\cos\left(4x\right)\right)}}
  \end{align}
  $$
- Another solution I tried was through manipulation and the use of trigonometric identities and formulae but to no avail. I tried substituting:

  - $\color{red}{\sin(4x)}$ with $\color{blue}{4\sin(x)\cos(x) - 8\sin(3x)\cos(x)}$ and then
  - $\color{red}{8\sin(3x)\cos(x)}$ with $\color{blue}{4\sin(4x)+4\sin(2x)}$.
    $$
    \begin{align}
    l
    & =\lim_{x→0}{{\sin^{200}(x)}\over{x^{199}\sin(4x)}}\\
    & =\lim_{x→0}{{\sin^{200}(x)}\over{x^{199}(4\sin(x)\cos(x) - 8\sin(3x)\cos(x))}}\\
    & =\lim_{x→0}{{\sin^{200}(x)}\over{x^{199}(4\sin(x)\cos(x) - 4\sin(4x)+4\sin(2x))}}\\
    \end{align}
    $$

No matter what I try, the limit remains $0/0$.

**Question:**

Does the above limit exist? If so, what I path should I follow to work out a solution?

Comment: It always amazes me that people do not study Standard limits first, before learning L'Hospital's Rule. A question like this should make clear the absolute importance of Standard limits.

Comment: Hopefully, it will to users that stumble upon this question in future @imranfat.

Comment: I actually presented this question in my class yesterday since L'Hospital's Rule is this week's topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that by standard limit

$${{\sin^{200}x}\over{x^{199}\sin(4x)}}={{\sin^{200}x}\over{x^{200}}}\cdot{{ 4x}\over{\sin(4x)}}\cdot\frac14\to1^{200}\cdot1\cdot\frac14=\frac14$$

Comment: Yes.Well done, Gimusi.

Comment: @PeterSzilas ops...with the edits I lost a $\frac14$, now it is fixed. Thanks Peter

Comment: Gimusi.We are a good team you lose 1/4, and I do not notice it.:))))

Comment: In the original post it was there but afetr a revision I've deleted involontary, thanks to you comment I noticed it! A great team!

Comment: Gimusi.I really did not notice it.:)))

Comment: Thanks a lot @gimusi. I was unaware that $\lim_{x -> 0}({sin(x)\over x}) = 1$.

Comment: You are welcome. Note that it is a fondamental standard limit, you should study this and others similar before to deal with more complicated limit and I suggest to avoid l’Hopital to solve limits because otherwise you don’t get the feeling about what is going on with the solution. Bye

Answer (score 2):

Since $\sin x= x+o(x)$ we have, $$\frac{\sin^{200}x}{x^{199}\sin(4x)}= \frac{x^{200}+o(x^{200})}{x^{199}(4x+o(x))}=\frac{x^{200}+o(x^{200})}{4x^{200}+o(x^{200})}=\frac{1+o(1)}{4+o(1)} =\to\frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: last step is not clear

Comment: Why ? is that not rthe euclidean division?

Comment: now it is complete and clear!

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with the big O notation, but thanks for giving me food for thought. +1

Comment: @AngelPolitis taylor expansion?

Comment: I just checked it out @GuyFsone; I was not aware, thanks!